# Fetching values/rows from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
      public function getMaxRID() {

            // open a connection to database 
            $conn = $this->getConnection();

            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("can not connect to database");
            }

            $query = "SELECT MAX(RID) AS MAXRID FROM Words";
            $result = $conn->query($query);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                echo $result->fetch_assoc()["MAXRID"];
            }
        }
```

This is my method that fetch maximum value of a field. In this case we know that we have just one row and one field "MAXRID". I got it with this method, But is it recommended way?
fetch_assoc() method is not in  the suggested list of $result object methods! But when I write this,Executes without any problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getMaxRID() {
            // open a connection to database 
            $conn = $this->getConnection();
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("can not connect to database");
            }
            $query = "SELECT MAX(RID) AS MAXRID FROM Words";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
                echo $result->row_array()["MAXRID"]; $result->free_result(); Unset($query);
            }
        }
```

- Changes:

  1) always use num_rows() function

  2) to retrieve one row always use row_array()

  3) use free_result() to release the memory in it

  4) unset the variables used in the query

Comment: Unsetting $query is not necessary, it gets released when the function is executed.

Comment: But it helps if you are using the same variable

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is not much wrong with your way, but you could fetch that one column directly because you only need the `MAXRID` value.

You are using `mySQLi`, `PDO` has a method to retrieve columns directly:

So i would recommend to make use of [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

```
if ($result->rowCount() > 0) 
{
    echo $result->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: FYI: the OP is using the mysqli API, not PDO

Comment: Your right my fault. Well i think there is no similar function for mysqli. Going to update my answer.

Comment: no worries no harm done :) just pointing some info.

Comment: @Ghost-Did you mean that methods such as fetch_assoc() and row_array() are used for PDO?

Comment: @MousaJafari no there are no methods such as `fetch_assoc()` in PDO, thats for mysqli. `->fetchColumn()` is for PDO as stated in this answer.

Comment: @Ghost But I using mysqli! Why I can't see them in my suggested list?!